# How to trim (space) the variables in the the assertion section in SoapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

How to trim (leading and trailing spaces) the variables in the the assertion section of SoapUI/ReadyAPI ?

```
Ex:
Input String : "Failure   "
Output String : "Failure"
```

[Ready API Assertion Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAPvD.png)

Comment: Do you mean trim or remove spaces from the value assigned to a var?

Comment: I mean removing spaces from the value assigned to a variable.

Comment: Would you mind providing the sample data (in the form of text, not image) and mention what kind of assertion are you using? And the issue? Issue neither clear from summary / description nor from your comments from below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some google, I got the XSLT/XPath method which does space trim of given variables in Assertion window.

Method name : normalize-space()

Usage would be like:
normalize-space(//Results[1]/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/PAYMNT_RQST.PAYMNT_STAT_CD[1])

normalize-space function collapses whitespace in a string. Specifically, it performs three steps:

1. Replaces each carriage return (#xD), line feed (#xA), and tab (#x9)
2. character with a single space (#x20) Collapses all consecutive
3. spaces into a single space Removes all leading and trailing spaces

Thanks

Comment: This is not a Groovy method, this is an XPath method.

Answer (score 15):

Use trim for trailing spaces.
Use replace to get rid of spaces.

```
def trimExample = "Some string to be trimmed.      ";
def trimmed = trimExample.trim();

def removeSpacesExample = "Some String To Lose All Spaces."
def removedSpaces = removeSpacesExample.replace(' ', '');
```

Use log.info(varName) to see the effect.

Comment: These method doe not work in Assertion popup in ReadyAPI.

Comment: It worked for me in a Script Assertion and Groovy Script.  I’ll re-check at work on Monday,

Comment: `trim` will also remove leading spaces, right? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_trim.htm

Comment: In case you need to remove any whitespace in the string, you can use `removeSpaceExample.replaceAll(/\s/,"")` or `removeSpaceExample.replaceAll("\\s","")` (whichever one you find easier to read)

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'Xpath Match' as of now

Could you try using 'XQuery Match' instead. it automatically trims the space

Sample Response where we have spaces after '-1   5   ' (so we will try to remove the spaces

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <ConversionRateResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
     <ConversionRateResult>-1       5    </ConversionRateResult>
  </ConversionRateResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Put the below code in XQuery Match

```
declare namespace soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
declare namespace ns1='http://www.webserviceX.NET/';


for $x in //ns1:ConversionRateResponse
return <Result>{data($x/ns1:ConversionRateResult)}</Result>
```

Below is the result, where you can see spaces behind the 5 are removed

```
<Result>-1       5</Result>
```

So for your example the code will be like below inside a XQuery Match

```
for $x in //ns:Results[1]/ns:Resultset[1]/ns:Row[1]
return <Result>{data($x/ns:LM_ELEC_PAYMNT_PAYMNT.PLCY_STAT_CD[1])}</Result>
```

The best thing would be using script assertion for such or any other complex operation. But above should be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got a simple method as i mentioned below. So could not try this. I am sure this will also help to resolve this issue.